Set the view directory and layout in ejs based on the path of the request
I have a little dilemma, where I am trying to make a website with a function for changing the views directory and the layout of a node.js server:
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const segments = req.path.split('/');
  const basePath = segments[1];

  switch (basePath) {
    case 'admin':
      app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/admin'));
      app.set('layout', path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts/admin'));
      break;
    case 'user':
      app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/worker'));
      app.set('layout', path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts/worker'));
      break;
    case 'guest':
      app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/user'));
     app.set('layout', path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts/user'));
      break;
    default:
      app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/def'));
      app.set('layout', path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts/def'));
      break;
  }

  next();
});

I have imported all of the modules that I need and I am doing app.use() for what is needed, the problem with this is that app.set sets the views directory and layout file globally, which means that it is going to cause problems when two or more users are accessing different routes at the same time. Is there another good way to do this? Call me dumb if I am, happy for help.

You can set configurations for each request separately.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const segments = req.path.split('/');
  const basePath = segments[1];

  switch (basePath) {
    case 'admin':
      res.locals.viewsDir = 'views/admin';
      res.locals.layout = 'layouts/admin';
      break;
    ...
  }

  next();
});
app.get('/:basePath/home', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home', {
    layout: res.locals.layout,
    title: 'Home Page',
  });
});


I think it's unnecessary, or actually even problematic, to constantly set the views and layouts directories. As you say, this brings more problems than it solves, mainly because of your exact problem: the views and layout directory is set for the whole application. A typical approach would be to have (in your case) 3 different Router, which each handle the request of admin, user and guest.
So you would set the views and layouts directories just once to views and views/layouts and handle the different types of users in their respective routes.
app.js
import adminRouter from '/path/to/adminFile.js';
import userRouter from '/path/to/userFile.js';
import guestRouter from '/path/to/guestFile.js';
// maybe also router for the default case, depending on how many subroutes there are
// import defRouter from '/path/to/defFile.js';
...
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('layout', path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts'))
...
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/guest', guestRouter);
// app.use('*', defRouter);
// or just handle the default routes individually here
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {...});

adminFile.js
import express from 'express'
const adminRouter = express.Router();

adminRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {...});
...
export default adminRouter;

And same thing with the other routers.
Then, you probably have some kind of session management implemented, so you can add more route handlers to routes that should only be accessed by a certain type of users. For example (using express-session):
adminFile.js
import express from 'express'
const adminRouter = express.Router();

const isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session.user.type === "admin") {
    next();
  } else {
    // redirect, send HTTP status code, do what you think would be appropiate
    res.redirect('/');
    // or
    res.status(403).end("Forbidden access to admin route");
    // or ...
  }
}

adminRouter.get('/', isAdmin, (req, res) => {...});
...
export default adminRouter;
...



Also no need to say Call me dumb if I am, we all start somewhere and need to understand things with time, you're not dumb, you're learning!
